# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, json.net

I am working in c# 4.0 to read a signed request I am using the following code

```
FacebookApp fap = new FacebookApp();
fap.AppId = "789485219211963"; // App ID
fap.AppSecret = "365ee9f5823698536767d608cf572a49"; 

string requested_Data = Request.Form["signed_request"];
FacebookSignedRequest fsr = fap.ParseSignedRequest(requested_Data);
IDictionary<string, string> myDic = fsr.Dictionary;

string name = myDic["name"];
string algorithm = myDic["algorithm"];

Response.Write(requested_Data + "<br>" + algorithm + "<br>" + name + "<br>");
```

But on the highlighted line I received following exception

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I downloaded Newtonsoft.Json. release 1 instead of release 2 but it still not working.
Can someone kindly help me to solve this problem, also please guide me either my way of reading signed request is correct or not if not please specify the correct way.

Thanks:

Comment: What highlighted line? What did you do with the download once you got it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm guessing you donwloaded Newtonsoft.Json v4.0, not 3.5. Last version of 3.5 is release 8.

http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/50552

I guess that you might be able to do a version forward in your web.config/app.config in order to use 4.0 instead of 3.5, because some library you are using is probably built against the 3.5 version of Newtonsoft.

Comment: Yes you are right, now I used Newtonsoft.json 3.5 from http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/50552 and it worked.
Thanks Jishi

Comment: For future reference on assembly forwarding configuration:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx

Answer (score 9):

You can update it with its nuget package 'Newtonsoft.Json' using the package manager.

```
PM> update-package newtonsoft.json
```

Answer (score 3):

In package manager console Visual Studio 2013

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Then restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into this problem, I found that there were 2 similar folders in yourproject/packages, one is version 6.0.5, another is 5.0.6.

I deleted the 5.0.6 and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Xamarin.Forms PCL WinPhone8.1 project after upgrading all NuGet packages for the solution. The problem was with Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0 in the winPhone8.1 project.

All other projects worked correctly.  Spent two days trawling all advice and finally resolved the problem by deleting the project, pulling a clone of the project from my git and adding back into the solution.  Still failed (although the git version worked fine before the commit.)

Deleted reference for Newtonsoft, reinstalled the old version 8.0.3, then upgraded via NuGet to V9.0.0.

Then deleted all references to Newtonsoft from the winPhone8.1 project Bin/ARM/Debug, Bin/x86/Debug and Obj/ARM/Debug/MSIL and MDIL directories.  Did a build and SUCCESS.

Comment: Very frustrating for me, but this is the only solution that has worked.  I have had real problems with versioning in NewtonSoft.Json in the past, and the situation does not appear to have improved over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Package Manager Console and execute the following:

```
update-package newtonsoft.json
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

PM> update-package newtonsoft.json It works

Comment: Could you add some details, to make your answer more helpful?

Comment: Not everyone might know that you tell him to execute the statement in the Package Manager Console.