# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

Tags: asp.net, json.net

I am getting the Error

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

for my CI build

Solution which I tried

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
        culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

It also did not work

Comment: The error means .NET couldn't find the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library. [Do you have it installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176841/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-3-5-0-0?rq=1)

Comment: Exact same problenm - driving me nuts. Let me know if you find a solution

Comment: Actually, for me adding what you tried solved the problem.

Comment: Use the consolidate option in NuGet package manager to ensure versions don't drift apart.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/361#issuecomment-181387928

Answer (score 259):

In package manager console execute: `Update-Package –reinstall Newtonsoft.Json`.

**UPDATE**

*I originally posted this as a comment but as @OwenBlacker suggested I'll just put it here:*

If you still get an error after doing this, then what worked for me eventually is that I deleted Json.Net's `<dependentAssembly>` section from my `.config` file. Reinstall brings it back if it's not there and apparently you need to delete it. Until there will be a normal solution in the package itself, I'm afraid this manual step is a must.

**Note: Please read the comments below before doing this.**

As per René's comment below **BE AWARE** that the command posted in the answer will reinstall the package in every project in your solution. So if you use the Newtonsoft.Json package in several projects and maybe use different versions, just executing the above command might have unwanted consequences.

Comment: For the sake of everyone reading this: I've done that and still got the error. Then I solved it somehow: Amazingly, I had to _delete_ Json.Net's `<dependentAssembly>` section from my `.config` file. Reinstall brings it back if it's not there and apparently you need to delete it. Until there will be a normal solution in the package itself, I'm afraid this manual step is a must.

Comment: @OferZelig You should post that as a separate answer, so it can get the upvotes (and, more importantly, increased attention). Not least because it worked for me too  :)

Comment: @OwenBlacker thanks. But because there are lots of answers already, mine will get lost. And this answer is quite good, it's just that if it doesn't work then my comment "completes" it. You know what? I guess I'll just edit the original answer. More important than gaining own rep.

Comment: _BE AWARE_ that the command posted in the answer will reinstall the package in _every_ project in your solution. So if you use the Newtonsoft.Json package in several projects and maybe use different versions, just executing the above command might have unwanted consequences.

Comment: Solved! For me, I had v6 installed in one project, reinstalling from package manager brought it up to v7.

Comment: Had to do this to get [GeoIP2-dotnet](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-dotnet) up and running.

Comment: i had the issue when i installed `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` then automatically `Newtonsoft.Json` was installed and version changed from 4.5.0.0 to 6.0.0.0 and then [this](http://westdiscgolf.blogspot.com/2014/02/updated-jsonnet-and-now-owin-errors.html) post helped which similar to @ZeroDotNet answer to make changes in `web.config` `<dependentAssembly>`, these recent update really effects the app, why they don't fix it

Comment: Thanks this worked. I don't understand what happened. I updated my Json through NuGet and then suddenly this library is gone?

Comment: The package manager command didn't work for me, but editing the app.config did. Thanks.

Comment: package manager command worked like a charm for me, why isn't this the accepted answer?

Comment: Old post but still having issues so recommend this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38715898/12377

Worked for me.

Comment: ahhh after hours wasted this fixed the package error.

Answer (score 137):

To everyone having problems with Newtonsoft.Json v4.5 version try using this in web.config or app.config:

```xml
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"
               publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

**IMPORTANT**: Check that the `configuration` tag of your config file has no namespace attribute (as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12011221/150370).  Otherwise, `assemblyBinding` tags will be ignored.

Comment: for me, deleting the content of the bin folder manually after cleaning (which does not empty it) did the trick after I applied this answer.

Comment: Works great! As of 7/4/15 the current version of Newtonsoft.Json is 7.0.0 so `newVersion="6.0.0.0"` must be changed to `newVersion="7.0.0.0"` or whatever version you are using

Comment: I had a similar problem with DNN and the newtonsoft.json.dll, where DNN used version 4.5 and my module wanted to use 7.0.  I didn't have access to upgrade the dnn installation with 7.0, so I added one of these dependentAssembly entries using oldversion= 0.0-7.0 and the 'new' version as the old 4.5.  It worked.

Comment: For me the issue was that I had installed the latest version (8.*) but needed to downgrade to (6.*) because of other projects, the dependent assembly in the downgraded projects app.configs was still referencing 8.0.0.0 as the version, needed to change this to 6.0.0.0

Comment: That note on the namespace...I could hug you. I burned hours on this not knowing the binding redirects were being ignored because of that.

Comment: The note about the namespace is so important that it could be an answer by its own. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 52):

**The key point is referencing right version in your config file.**

**Steps;**

1- look at what is the version of your Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the project reference property  what ever the version in your package folder (For example mine is 7.0.1 and the reference Version is 7.0.0.0)

2- look at what the project expect from you in the exception (mine is 6.0.0.0)

3- Add dependent assembly to your config file as it should be..

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"  publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Sorry can give only one vote your point (For example mine is 7.0.1 and the referance Version is 7.0.0.0) made a huge difference. I would have given more.....Thanks :)

Comment: This worked for me. I updated the version to 7, but it was really running version 8 so I just changed the newVersion to 8.0, thanks!

Comment: Even though installing 8.0.3 (like it says in nuget package manager), the .dll under references is still 8.0.0. So I changed to 8.0.0.0 in my web.config. Wierd how this worked yesterday when I published everything and this morning it does not work anymore.

Comment: How do you find the reference version? Using 12.0.3.0 in the redirect doesn't work but 12.0.0.0 does. Without pure fluke, how would I have worked that out? Is it detailed somewhere? It was unable to find 12.0.3.0 which exists in the bin folder, but it can find 12.0.0.0 apparently which literally doesn't exist as a versioned assembly ha!

Answer (score 27):

I had no luck with any of the solutions presented here (uninstalling, reinstalling, deleting references, creating bindingRedirects etc.)  I had to go back to an old version of Newtonsoft.  Version 5.0.6 had been working before, so I tried that one.  I had to enter these two commands in the Package Console:

`uninstall-package newtonsoft.json -force`

`install-package newtonsoft.json -version "5.0.6"`

The `-force` option in the first command is required to force the uninstall.  Dependencies with other assemblies prevent the uninstall without it.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Had the error in my MVC 4 project. Almost switched to the native serializer.

Comment: thanks, I just needed to change -version "5.0.6" to -pre:
install-package newtonsoft.json -pre

Answer (score 25):

I fixed the problem adding this binding redirect to my .config file:

```
<runtime>
    . . . 
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
                culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

The error message complains about not finding version 4.5.0.0, the current version of Newtonsoft.Json is 6.0.0.0 so the redirect should go from 4.5 to 6.0, not viceversa

Comment: Yes this solved my problem. So strange the amount of issues JSON.NET causes.. but once it goes its a dream machine. Thanks +1

Comment: Your code snippet made me realize was missing 'assemblyBinding' element. Thanks

Answer (score 22):

I think you are pointing to the wrong target, change it to 4.5 instead of 6.0

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
        culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This should work.

Comment: Umbraco 7 required 4.5.0.0, so this helped get it up and running

Answer (score 22):

I've spend couple of days trying to resolve this frustrating issue. I've tried pretty much everything that can be found on the web. Finally I found that this error could be caused (like in my case) by the different target .Net project versions (4.5 and 4.5.1) in one solution. The steps bellow fixed it for me:

1. Double check the .Net version of every project that's in your solution. Just right click on project and go to `Properties`.

[image]

2. If possible set the same .Net version for *all* projects. If not at least try to change the Startup project one (for me this was the one causing the issues).
3. Remove all `Newtonsoft.Json` packs from the solution.

   `uninstall-package newtonsoft.json -force`
4. Update all `Newtonsoft.Json` versions in all `packages.config` files, like so

   `<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />`
5. Reinstall `Newtonsoft.Json` from "Package Manager Console" with:

   `install-package newtonsoft.json`
6. Rebuild the solution

(Optional) 7. If you changed the Startup project, return it again

Answer (score 15):

```
uninstall-package newtonsoft.json -force
install-package newtonsoft.json
```

Did the trick for me :)

Comment: this did the trick for me too.
it automatically updated the webconfig file to the correct version.

Comment: Me too, this really helped.

Comment: Other answers didn't work for me but this! It automatically updated both web.config and packages.config, thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

if you using multiple project in same solution 
and library of the one other 
check is all projects has same version of Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: This was my issue. Very frustrating going through all the responses above and getting no results. Finally figured it out when I bothered to check the version of the .dll in my Build folder.

Answer (score 11):

Remove the Newtonsoft.Json assembly from the project reference and add it again. You probably deleted or replaced the dll by accident.

Comment: This approached works against a Xamarin Forms iOS project where I dropped the NuGet package and re-added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I was writing a WebApi REST service client, so for me this error was caused by adding References to the `System.Net.Http` and `System.Net.Http.Formatting` assemblies manually via Add Reference, when I should have added the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package via **NuGet**.
See also [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928352/2066744).

Answer (score 8):

You have 2 different versions of JSON.NET library in your solution. To solve this you should upgrade them to latest version. Follow these steps:

1-Open solution explorer
2-Right Click on solution name
3-Select Manage Nuget Packages for Solution
4-Select Updates from menu
5-Update JSON.NET package

This will resolve your issue.

link: 
[Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202038/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-7-0-0-0-culture-neutr/38202870#38202870)

Comment: The easiest and safest way to fix this problem. Thanks @mohammad

Answer (score 7):

**Deploy the correct version to the CI machine**

This is telling you that the assembly loader found a different version of the `Newtonsoft.Json` assembly, that does not match the reference you created in your project. To load the assembly correctly, you must either deploy the assembly side by side with your compiled code, or install the correct version of the assembly in the destination machine (i.e. in the GAC).

**Alternative: make sure the configuration is in the correct file**

If you want to keep the current solution, and load an assembly with a different version, make sure that the configuration you posted is in the correct `.config` file. Remember that there is no `xpto.dll.config`, a DLL loaded by an application always uses the config file of the running application.

Answer (score 6):

Normally adding the binding redirect should solve this problem, but it was not working for me. After a few hours of banging my head against the wall, I realized that there was an xmlns attribute causing problems in my web.config. After removing the xmlns attribute from the configuration node in Web.config, the binding redirects worked as expected.

http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/10/02/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version4-5-0-0.aspx

Answer (score 5):

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"
        publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Works for me.... just put the version you are using in newVersion i.e(newVersion="7.0.0.0")

Comment: Had this problem some times ago and this fixed in one hit. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Close solution.

Open `packages.config` and `*.csproj` with text editor and delete any line have Newtonsoft.Json

Ex:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json,Version=9.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Or

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Open solution again and re-install Newtonsoft.Json by `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

It work for me.

Comment: it works sometime but in the upcoming builds this problem came again n again

Comment: No problem if don't update it haha. Create trash project and install Newtonsoft.Json.dll, copy it (file dll) and add to your project reference.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting same error and by adding below code error resolved on production.

Answer is too late but might help someone.

```
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

Comment: Should add </runtime> at the last line

Answer (score 4):

We had the exact same issue that you mentioned. We're using nunit to run tests through CI, and we have nunit running a file called tests.nunit, which describe a list of test dll fixtures to run.

Each test fixture had their own config file, but when run through the "tests.nunit" file the binding redirects seem to be ignored. The solution was to add the binding redirects to a new config file, "tests.config" that was beside the "tests.nunit" file.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

You should update the web.config file in the server.
When nuget install NewtonSoft update this file including this code

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: In my case that was exactly my solution, put into app.config. "Assembly versions can be redirected in application, publisher policy, or machine configuration files."

Answer (score 4):

I have got the same type of problem. And I also solved it just doing the following:
Go to ***TOOLS*** > ***NuGet Package Manager*** and Select ***Package Manager Console***. Finally, execute the following two commands :)

1. **uninstall-package newtonsoft.json -force**
2. **install-package newtonsoft.json**

Answer (score 4):

Just check the version of **Newtonsoft.Json** [Newtonsoft properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA4ig.png)

Then you need to add that version in your web config (in my case 8.0.0.0)
[Web config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM1Gl.png)

Answer (score 3):

I made the mistake of adding a NewtonSoft .dll file for .Net 4.5.

My main project *was* 4.5, but when I added an extra project to my solution, it strangely added it as a .Net 2.0 project...  and when I attempted to use NewtonSoft's 4.5 dll with this, I got this "Newtonsoft.Json couldn't be found" error.

The solution (of course) was to change this new project from .Net 2.0 to 4.5.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same error and struggled with it for hours. I had a web API project which is using Newtonsoft.json and another UnitTest project for the web API project. The unit test project also needed the Newtonsoft.json reference. But on adding the link I was getting the above exception.

I finally resolved it by adding the below code snippet in the app.config of the unit test project:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>

Comment: I was having this same problem when I upgraded Nestwonsoft.Json while still using and old version of WebAPI, and this solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the main project was **still referencing an old version of Newtonsoft.Json** which didn't exists in the project any more (shown by a yellow exclamation mark). Removing the reference solved the problem, no bindingRedirect was necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem with version 7.0.0.0, and the lib causing my problem was [Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime/) which somehow was referring to the wrong version (6.0.0.0) of Newtonsoft.json, despite the right dependency management in nugget (the right version of newtonsoft.json (7.0.0.0) was installed).

I solved this by applying the redirection above from 6.0.0.0 to 7.0.0.0 (from Kadir Can) in the config file:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
```

----> After a few days without changing anything it came up again with the same error. I installed version 6.0.0.0 n updated it to 7.0.0.0 it works fine now.

Comment: Worked for me. Installed version Newtonsoft Json 7.0.1 (beta), but the config generated was pointing to 6.0.0.0 which was not correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Reinstall newtonsoft package through nuget did not worked for me. 
I had to manually call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to bypass this issue

I changed

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
MyObject data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>();
```

For

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string jsonStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MyObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonStr);
```

Comment: I have found that instead of calling the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>() directly, you can add the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package from NuGet to get the updated version of System.Net.Http.Formatting.  This will allow you to use the response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>() call and let Json.Net work behind the scenes.

Comment: Bioupy, your suggession worked for me.
In my project we use Newtonsoft.Json version=9.0.0.0 (as a NuGet package) and Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client version=5.2.3 (also as NuGet).
It seems that the System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll has a strict version reference to Newtonsoft.Json.dll of version=6.0.0.0.
So it tried to load version 6.0.0.0, but I couldn't put 2 Newtonsoft.Json assemblies of 2 different versions in my application target folder.
So reading the response as string and deserializing it with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject resolved my case.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, after downloading the assembly and adding the reference to the project, I solved this by 'unblocking' the DLL before adding the reference to the project.

Using Windows explorer, browse to the DLL location, right-click on the DLL and then select 'properties'.  You'll find an 'unblock' button on one of the tabs and then you can add the reference and the assembly will load correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing from above helped me, but what actually fixed it is the following:

1. **Remove all dependency bindings in app.config** (from all app.config files in the solution)
2. Execute the following command from **"Package Manager Console"**

**Get-Project -All | Add-BindingRedirect**

3. Rebuild

Reference:
http://blog.myget.org/post/2014/11/27/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-NuGet-Assembly-Redirects.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Right click your project select manage Nuget packages, type newtonsoft in the search box and install the latest version. Then Run your App

Answer (score 2):

Another insidious problem is that it appears that binding redirects can just silently fail if the  element has an incorrect configuration on any other dependentAssembly elements.

Ensure that you only have one  element under each  element.

In some instances, VS generates this:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity ...
    <assemblyIdentity ...
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Instead of

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity ...
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity ...
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Took me a long time to realise this was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Below section add in to your web.config

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"
               publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 2):

If error disappears locally and still appears on server, the solution that works with me is to delete bin folder and packages.config and web.config and reupload these files

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was a depreciated version of Newtonsoft.Json. Re-installing didn't help.

In Visual Studio, go to Tools->Manage NuGet Packages. Select Updates. Search for Newtonsoft. Click Update to install the latest version.

Comment: The latest version isn't always the right approach - for us v6 broke some inherited serialisation that had worked just fine in v4.

Comment: You can always revert back to the old version if you experience side effects.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. 13.0.1 was installed but upgrading to 13.0.3 worked.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in a CI environment with NuGet restore, be sure that you don't have partial folders checked into source control. By default, when adding folders to source control, it will automatically exclude assemblies. Besides, this defeats the whole purpose of restoring nuget packages upon build. Either checking assemblies, or not checking in any packages folders will get a successful build, but the better practice is to not check nuget packages into source control.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by installing the Nuget package: Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client Libraries. This in turn installed newtonsoft.json version 6.04

Answer (score 1):

One more advice to the open topic. The error appears after running the "Analyze": something was changed in the project settings. The problem was that in:

*Project / Settings / Build / Platform target*

appeared **"Any CPU"**.

Setting back to **x86** (or maybe **x64** in your case) solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
updating web.config with the following assembly binding resolved the issue 
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">     
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
                culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simplest solution you can set your project file to automatically generate binding redirects for you:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
</PropertyGroup>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program to fix this automatically. It will ensure that your program is able to use the latest version of the target assemblies on your hard drive, not just the ones your dependent libraries want.

https://github.com/BackTrak/DependencyFixup/releases/tag/1.0.0.0

No more guessing, it will fix all the manifest reference issues for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the installed version of ur library from the properties inside references. For my case i had 8.0.0.0 installed. Error says `Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.`

So i had to add the following manually inside web.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with it for a day or so too, tried every solution.
What helped me was to check that capital letters in app.config. I had PublicKeyToken instead of publicKeyToken, after changing it suddenly worked.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from many answers here,I found something hence adding it.First point,Make sure the dll is not referenced from GAC.Apart from this,

While adding/changing dll of Newtonsoft.Json ,Sometimes *.csproj of the project doesnt get changed or the changed version of json dll will not be reflected in csproj of the solution.

So Open the project in notepad++ and search Newtonsoft.Json and rename the JSON from old version to New version explicitly.Now after tabbing back to VS ,the solution/project will reload with needed version Newtonsoft.JSON dll.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had folder name Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.7

[image]

but `.csproj` file had path though folder `...\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.5\...`

[image]

Changing `.csproj` file to have 6.0.7 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, seems still many people having issues with the same thing. So I would like to share my experience that it might help someone.

I had the same issue in two places. In one project users 6.0.4.0 and in different project use 4.5.0.0.

1- This work for me. In bin folder I have 6.0.0.0 Newtonsoft.Json.dll and symbolic link to 4.5.0.0 dlls

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
<probing privatePath="bin\4.5dlls-path;" />
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" 
culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

If you don't know how to create symbolic link [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).

mklink /D "name of the folder" "Path to the dll"

2- In this case when I remove the  secion from Web config file it worked. Remember I have reference to 6.0.0.0 and 4.5.0.0 in different projects. In symbolic link I had 12.0.1.0 dll and bin 6.0.0.0.

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
<probing privatePath="bin\12.0.1dlls-path;" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

3- I have one more solution. If you have different versions of Newtonsoft.Json.dll in different projects try to upgrade all into one version or to the latest version, But in some case it might not work. Ex: System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll might need the version of Nettonsoft.Json.dll 6.0.0.0. In this case you need the vision 6.0.0.0, so try to make all into same version. Hope this might help some one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I got the exception when I was trying to create MassTransit queues:

```
"Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MassTransit.Serialization.JsonMessageSerializer' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"
```

Solution that worked for me (after spending couple of days reverting several commits):

- We had a windows service solution that has .Service project and .XUnitTests project. Both of them were using a common nuget that has dependency on Newtonsoft.Json.dll. There was no explicit reference to Newtonsoft.Json nuget package in both projects (but we were using 'using Newtonsoft.Json;' namespace in our classes), so the common nuget was using version 9 of Newtonsoft.Json by default.
- As soon as I installed the Newtonsoft.Json nuget in both .Service and .XUnitTests projects, the common nuget package started using the latest v12 Newtonsoft and that fixed my issue.

Just posting it in here if it saves anyone their valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from 2022.
Was getting a similar exception error to this:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

The fix was to go into Web.config file for the project and make the following edits:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
        culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```