# Unable to perform Azure BizTalk Hybrid Connection - on-premisis part

Tags: azure, biztalk, azure-mobile-services

Just getting started using Azure Mobile Services.

Decided to create a BizTalk Hybrid Connection to use with my SQL server running on an Azure Windows VM.

Done the portal part of creating the Hybrid connection, and proceeded onto configuring the on-premises part.

Immediately ran into the following error popup: CmdletInvocationException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtownsoft.Json, Verson=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral ' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: A thread over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-4-5-0-0-culture-neutr that has some things you could try, not specific to Azure Hybrid Connection though

Comment: Thanks for your response! All those issues in the thread you referenced are related to various Visual Studio projects. In my case - there is no such project. I was finishing the BizTalk Hybrid Connection on-premisis install by clicking on the "On Premisis setup" within Azure BizTalk setup Web page. When I clicked that link, I got a Hybrid Connection Manager loaded on my Server's desktop. During that process, this Hybrid Connection Manage ran into this "... unable to load Newtonsoft.Json" error. Maybe there is a way to install Newtonsoft.Json directly into the server's GAC?

Comment: You can download and install it from  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: I have tried to do this: 1) created a VS project and added Newtonsoft.Json v 4.5.1 nuget to it 2) ran gacutil.exe /if and pointed it to the location of json dll. Instead of installing this assembly into GAC, I got: "Unknown option:  studio"

Comment: Well, I have managed to install Newtonsoft.Json 4.5 directly to GAC. Now, I'm getting another error: Inheritance security rules were violated by type Syste.Net.Httpformatting.JsonContractResolver. I gues, this is a fancy way of saying "Hybrid Connections are busted". I will have to wait until MS fixes that

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can download the Hybrid Connection Manager from here as an .msi from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42962

Follow the install instructions and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, I did a Nuget for
"Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.1"

then installed into the gac: gacutil /i Newtonsoft.Json.dll.

I ran into the same errors mentioned previously when using version"4.5.1", and 5.0.1 seemed to resolve this issue.