# Visual Studio Debugging dll dependency error

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis, dll

In Visual Studio 2015, I have Project A (Web Api Application) and Project B (MVC Application) in the same solution.

I can debug application A and application B separately.
But, When application B calls rest api from A, I receive dll dependency error from application A.

"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference".

When I clean build project A, at the first time call is successful, however subsequent calls receive same error.

How can I fix  this?

(I use IIS 7.5)

Comment: Consolidate your NuGet packages.

Comment: @Ahmet Altun, Could you debug your two projects now? If you get any latest information, please feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please mark sure that your two projects used the same Newtonsoft.Json version.

You can run the following command:

**update-package Newtonsoft.Json -reinstall**

Please also view your web.config, maybe you could remove the old version like:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />   </dependentAssembly>
```

Generally if we want to ensure all  Newtonsoft.Json packages are the same version, we also can specify the version:

**update-package Newtonsoft.Json -version 6.0.0 -reinstall**

Reference:

[Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794225/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-7-0-0-0)

http://blog.myget.org/post/2014/11/27/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-NuGet-Assembly-Redirects.aspx