# Newtonsoft.json throws error in Google Drive SDK

Tags: c#, .net, json, google-drive-api

I am trying to use Google drive SDK to upload files to Google Drive.

```
DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
     HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = "Application Name",
});
```

On reaching the above code,below given exception gets thrown.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have tried updating, uninstalling and reinstalling Newtonsoft.json. But none worked. Tried editing web.config as below, but didn't work..

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-4-5-0-0-culture-neutr

Comment: @PranavPatel... Tried...but didn't work for me...