# Newtonsoft.Json version 8.0.2 Could not load file or assembly Error

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-assembly

I'm attempting to parse a JSON file in Class Library within an Web API solution. It is a regular C# Class Library, not the Portable kind.

I've tried every single answer [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-4-5-0-0-culture-neutr), but it still doesn't work! I keep getting the same error which is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed

Here is the code:

```
public IList<BranchRM> AllBranches()
{
    var result = new List<BranchRM>();
    var dataSourcePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Data/branches.json";
    var dataAsText = File.ReadAllText(dataSourcePath);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataAsText)) return result;
    var branchList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Branch>>(dataAsText);
    result = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<BranchRM>>(branchList);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: have you tried Reinstalling  `Newtonsoft.Json` via `Nuget` ?

Comment: Yep by doing `Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Reinstall`, still didn't work.

Comment: You can add reference to `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` directly, without `Nuget`. it resides in same directory as `Solution` under `Packages` Folder.

Comment: Thanks @tchelidze I just did, but still get the same error :(

Comment: Have updated `Newtonsoft.Json` package recently ? Probably, it is cached in `GAC` and `VS` tries to load from `GAC`, but since there is version mismatch(`GAC` stores older version than you have referenced currently), you get following error. Try to find `Newtonsoft.Json` in `GAC` and delete it.

Comment: Try to check GAC for Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0

Comment: I just looked at the GAC folders (through Agent Ransack), but found no files with the word `Newtonsoft` :(

Comment: Hey @Ciwan ...Did you ever got this resolved ?

Comment: @AmitTyagi sadly I did not :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was fixing some old code in one of my Windows Phone 8 solutions and thought of updating the NuGet packages and was greeted with the same issue.

A comment from StivOstenberg [here](https://github.com/jammerware/margiebot/issues/9) helped me solve this.

This is what I did:

1. Removed the NuGet package. Just clicked 'Uninstall' from NuGet manager. **Make sure to remove it from every project in the solution separately**.
2. Clean Solution. Rebuild Solution.
3. Now, remove the using statement from your entire solution! Can be done with a quick find and replace for *using Newtonsoft.Json* on 'Entire Solution'.
4. Repeat step 2. (Ignore the errors)
5. Add package again from NuGet manager & build (Ctrl+Shift+B).
6. Finally (almost), **for every error shown**, go to the particular page and **add reference again**.
7. Repeat step 2 and Run.

There might be some redundant steps, but this is exactly what I did, and it worked. Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are **no conflicting versions of Newtonsoft in a parent assembly!**

In a child-assembly I wanted to use Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3.

Well the StartUp project is an MVC5 web app. There I use the BundleTransformer.Less.X.X.X which had a dependency to Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.2. **Upgrading** NewtonSoft.Json to 8.0.3 (all the same version now) resolved it for me.