# Assembly Load exception in unit test project

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, json.net, crm, gated-checkin

In solution, I have three projects plugin, workflow, unit test.
In plugin and workflow, I am using newtonsoft json assembly.
but in unittest project, I am not using newtonsoft json assembly.

In plug in and workflow projects, I am calling external azure service using Webrequest, Webresponse and there I am passing serialized data of object. For Conversion of object to json, I am using newtonsoft.json assembly.

For code coverage of plug in and workflow projects , I have created fakes of system assembly and Shim of WebRequest, WebResponse. Those unit test cases are working perfectly in my local.

But when I check in my code in Gated TFS, my check-in is rejected. I checked log for rejection and rejection reason is : 
System.IO.fileloadexception : could not load assembly or file "newtonsoft.json".

have anyone faced such issue.?
This issue is either regarding project assembly or regarding gated build.

Comment: Which build are you using? Vnext and XAML?

Comment: Hi.. XAML..Gated build..

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT..  any solution

Comment: Could you build it successfully on the build agent manually? Please check if it's duplicate with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-4-5-0-0-culture-neutr  and using nuget package to solve the issue.