# Reproducing Newtonsoft.Json assembly version conflict

Tags: c#, json.net

I've set out to consistently reproduce the assembly version conflict in Newtonsoft.Json (related to my previous question [Why is Newtonsoft.Json so prone to assembly version conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650761/why-is-newtonsoft-json-so-prone-to-assembly-version-conflicts)) in order to better understand it, but I can't trigger it.

From the top answer there, it should happen if I have project A which references one version of Json.NET, then it references a project B which itself references a different version (and they don't have assembly redirects to handle the issue).

I've made a solution with a Class Library project and a Command Line project, both of which reference Newtonsoft.Json which I installed with Nuget Package Manager for both projects, and then I edited the Class Library packages.config to use an older version:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

While the Command Line project references the most recent version:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
```

This does not trigger the problem, however, the project still builds successfully and executes (I just serialize a string and print it from both projects, and I call the DLL from the EXE to ensure it tries to load both versions of Newtonsoft.Json.

I've uploaded the test project at https://github.com/sashoalm/ReproduceNewtonsoftJsonBug if needed.

Why isn't the bug getting triggered?

Comment: Is `Specific Version` set to true or false for the Newtonsoft references? http://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/img/troubleshooting-guide/visual-studio-tg/missing-assembly-references/fig3.png

Comment: @mjwills It is set to true, I just checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, despite what `packages.json` file says - your console application references version 6, not 10:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

However if you fix that (by uninstalling and reinstalling package for example) - it will still work fine. That is because there is automatic binding redirection in this case, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions):

> Starting with Visual Studio 2013, new desktop apps that target the
>   .NET Framework 4.5.1 use automatic binding redirection. This means
>   that if two components reference different versions of the same
>   strong-named assembly, the runtime automatically adds a binding
>   redirection to the newer version of the assembly in the output app
>   configuration (app.config) file.

If you look at output `ConsoleApp5.exe.config` file (*not* app.config in Visual Studio but in Debug\Release folder) - you will notice that binding redirects were automatically added there:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

If you remove them and then run target exe - it will fail at runtime.

That automatic binding redirecting is controlled by a property in .csproj file. If you open your console app .csproj you will see in one of the `PropertyGroup`s:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

If you change `true` to `false` - you will disable this feature and will see that warning you were trying to reproduce.

Comment: Hm, I can't find app.config in bin\Debug. There is only ConsoleApp5.exe.config and Newtonsoft.Json.xml, but they don't mention a Newtonsoft.Json version.

Comment: Yes I mean that `ConsoleApp5.exe.config`.

Comment: Oh, OK. But that config file only has one `<supportedRuntime>` key. Is it different for you (in case you compiled it)? Maybe I should just add the keys.

Comment: Did you fix your first problem I mentioned in answer? Check in your ConsoleApp5 .csproj file if you really reference version 10 of Newtonsoft.Json or still version 6 (as in your original project I downloaded from your link). You have nuget package version 10 installed, but really still reference version 6.

Comment: Just did it, it works now (or rather doesn't - it throws the exception). Thanks! I uploaded my changes to github - basically I disabled the binding redirects and changed the csproj like you said.