# Getting Error as Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I installed some frameworks

```
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
Microsoft.Owin.Cors
```

After adding these, I'm getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Please guide me as to how I can overcome this issue.

Comment: Have you installed [Newtonsoft.Json?](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). Make sure you have the right version. You should be able to find it easily from the nuget package manager in visual studio too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-4-5-0-0-culture-neutr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came a cross this issue for some years ago and the little bastard that is creating the issue is the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.

For some reason, if no newtonsoft package is installed when installing the Owin.Security.OAuth it will install it's required version but don't automatic upgrade it's reference to a newer if you install a newer newtonsoft package.

To solve it, first, uninstall the newtonsoft package

```
uninstall-package Newtonsoft.Json -Force
```

Then reinstall it

```
install-package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Then finally, update the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth package

```
update-package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
```

Answer (score 0):

via `NuGet` type this:

Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 10.0.2

More details here
[Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)