# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, thingworx, historian

I am completely new to .net applications.
I am currently working on connecting historian 5.5 and thingworx using .net SDKs.
The SDKs are already developed by someone else and I'm just creating a service and trying to run the service.
The service is created but when I run the console application, I have an exception being raised and it is as follows -

> > An exception has occurred, the process will exit:
> >     System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> >     'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
> >     located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> >     reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name:
> >     'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' ---> System.IO.FileLoadException:
> >     Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0,
> >     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
> >     dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
> >     match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
> >     File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> at com.thingworx.Configuration.Read()    at
>   com.thingworx.Configuration..ctor() in
>   d:\Users\salexander\Documents\Product\Edge
>   SDKs\ProficyLibrary\ProficyHistorian6.0SP1\Source
>   Code\ProficyConnector\Configuration.cs:line 272    at
>   com.thingworx.proficy.ProficyConfiguration..ctor()    at
>   com.thingworx.proficy.console.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\hernandez.fs\Documents\ProficyHistorianConnector\ProficyHistorian6.0SP1\Source
>   Code\ProficyConnectorConsole\Program.cs:line 16

It would be great if I could get a solution, I tried all the possible ways.
I just have the .exe application and I dont know what I need to do?
The application needs to run and the command prompt should stay idle with an option of quit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are relying on Newtonsoft.Json which does not appear to be installed. Try installing that package and see if that error goes away.

Here is another SO post where this question was answered more in depth:

[Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-4-5-0-0-culture-neutr)