# Error: "Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json" appears during runtime after merging two branches. Both branches run fine on their own

Tags: c#, json.net

I've been stuck with this bug after merging two branches together. The solution builds with no issues, but as soon as I call any function that uses `Newtonsoft.Json` I get the following exception at runtime:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

I've looked around and have tried:

- Re-installing the nuget package on the affected project
- Re-installing the nuget package on all projects running Newtonsoft.Json
- Updating all projects in the solution to be the same version of Newtonsoft.Json, then cleaning and 
  rebuilding the solution
- Digging through .csproj files to find Newtonsoft references and manually updating them to the same 
  version.

When I manually copy and paste the `6.0.0.0` dll into the debug folder I get no issues, however as soon as I clean/ rebuild Visual Studio puts the wrong dll version into the folder again. Even after updating the Nuget package in the affected project to the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json the error still states that it is looking for version `6.0.0.0` rather than `12.0.0.0`.

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Using **.net Framework 4.7**

Just to clarify: when I say "wrong dll" I meant it puts the dll that I want it to use in the bin folder (`12.0.0.0`), but the program see's it as the wrong version, expecting version `6.0.0.0`.

Comment: Is there anything that need update? You're using .net core or what?

Comment: This link might be of help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-4-5-0-0-culture-neutr

Comment: @Cooper1810 has the right answer.  However, in your case, you are going to want to point at version 12.0.0.0

Comment: Just edited the post to clarify some info.

Comment: @Cooper1810 Unfortunately I've tried the solutions posted there with no success. My project has no app.config/ web.config to update the values the top answer suggests if the reinstall does not work

Comment: hi @SomeGuy, is there a Console Application on your solution?

Comment: @PedroCoelho Afraid not, the project in question is a library which is loaded into some other projects

Comment: Alright, believe the issue is being caused by Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client. After uninstalling Newtonsoft.Json I found I was still able to build. The 12.0.0.0 version of NewtonSoft.Json was still added to the output folder but the same issue occurred when PostAsJsonAsync was called

Comment: Undid the merge, updated newtonsoft.json in the merging branch, tested it, worked fine with 12.0.0.0, re-did the merge... same error... I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

Was finally able to get it working. Ditched 12.0.0.0 completely, does not seem that there is a way to get Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client working with any version beyond 6.0.0.0