# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I know this kind of question has been asked before:e.g. [Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-4-5-0-0-culture-neutr)

But none of the answers to that question solved my problem. I've actually had similar issues with Google packages in the past.

My full exception message is:
`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=185c282632e132a0' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

I've tried re-installing the NuGet package. 
I've tried adding the dependency to my app.config:

```
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2" publicKeyToken="185c282632e132a0" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution.

My Nuget manager screen:
[image]

The DLLs are in the bin/Debug and bin/Release folders:
[image]

I actually just noticed that I have 1.4 installed and it's saying 1.2 is missing, so why is it looking for 1.2? If I downgrade the BigQuery.v2 package to 1.2 my project runs, but why is 1.4 saying that the 1.2 file is missing?

Comment: is that package listed in your .csproj file? and if so what version is it expecting there?

Comment: Yes it is. It shows the version installed by Nuget. 1.4.0 even though it says 1.2.0 is not found

Comment: ARGH! I found the issue: I have several projects in the solution that use "Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2" and one was still on 1.2.0 when the others were using 1.4.0. *facepalm*

Comment: If you have any issue with the use of Google Cloud Platform libraries, you can contact the [Google Cloud Platform Support Team](https://cloud.google.com/support) so they can look into this issue.