# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' on specific machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, json.net

I have a solution which runs pretty nice on 2 machines, but when I try to deploy same solution on specific machine which runs Windows Server 2012(irrelevant because another two instances also run on Windows Server 2012) it keep me throwing:
       `Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`
I've checked all my dependencies and they seem to be ok, may it be something with ASP.NET on machine?

*All my project use Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.1

Comment: is .net framework installed correctly on the machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176841/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-3-5-0-0)

Comment: Check all the `packages.config` in all your projects. One of them might be using older verison of `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: Check the `bin` folder on that machine and check if `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` is present, if not upload it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Newtonsoft.Json` is not part of .Net framework. You need to provide it yourself.

The exception you see means either:

1. `Newtonsoft.json.dll` is not part of your deployment and 2 machines where your solution works have this dll somehow installed
2. You have 2 conflicting versions of this dll and the solution does not know which one to pick.

So first check that this dll is present in your `bin` folder. If not, put it there.